# RNN LSTM for Sequential classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm learning about RNN LSTM for Sequential classification.

I did the vectorization of the data into sequences as needed.
Please check my sample [vectorized file here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APLPZ9egTlSMDoGGr8R7mbNOBG-4kbCR/view?usp=sharing) It has 10 features with 14 timesteps. So 140 Columns and rows are in the sample.

Now when I try to fit a very basic LSTM network here then I'm getting the following error:

```
epochs = 10
batch_size = 10000
time_steps = 14
features = 10

X = final_vectorized.loc[:, final_vectorized.columns != 'converted'].values
X=np.reshape(X,(7263,140,1))
Y = final_vectorized.loc[:,'converted'].values

train_X1=X[0:2500, :,:]
train_X2=X[4000:6500,:,:]
train_X = np.concatenate((train_X1, train_X2), axis=0)
test_X=X[2501:3999,:,:]
train_Y1=Y[0:2500]
train_Y2=Y[4000:6500]
train_Y = np.concatenate((train_Y1, train_Y2), axis = 0)
test_Y=Y[2501:3999]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM (100, dropout=0.2, input_shape=(time_steps, features)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print (model.summary())
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, validation_data=(test_X, test_Y), epochs=epochs,batch_size=10000)
```

**Error I'm getting is:**

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 14, 10), found shape=(None, 140, 1)

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Your time_steps should be 140, the same as X.shape[1]

Comment: To add to the above comment, you got 140 features per record in total. You're reshaping it to `(140, 1)` in data, however, your `input_shape` says `(14, 10)`. Change one to match the other.

Answer (score 0):

The following variables should be initialized correctly:

```
time_steps = 140
features = 1
```

Otherwise, the input should be reshaped:

```
X = np.reshape(X, (7263, 14, 10))
```

Either way, it will work. The actual solution depends on the data you're working with.